# How to calculate the strong isospin of an interaction?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, isospin-symmetry

I am given the following interaction :

$$pp \rightarrow H K^+ K^+ $$

In order for this interaction to happen the charge value, strong isospin, strangeness and baryon number must be the same on both sides.

For the electric charge we have +2 on both sides. This means that the H particle should be without charge.

For the strangeness we have 0 on the left side and 2 on the right side. That means that the H particle must have a -2 strangeness.

As for the baryon number, it is 2 on the left side and 0 on the right. That means that the H particle must have it's baryon number equal to 2.

Now I cannot calculate the isospin. I am not sure if we calculate it by summing the isospins on each side or multiplying them. The proton has a 1/2 isospin. I should get a +1 value for the left side. Is it correct to calculate it this way? Meaning, summing the isospin values of all the particles in a side?

Comment: The $K^+$s are isodoublet members, so with $I=1/2$ and $I_3=1/2$, just like the protons. Knowing little about your *H*, you might as well assume it is an isosinglet, even though it could be the neutral member of an isotriplet, *I* =1.  Good thing you are not asked about the spin.

Comment: No, I was simply asked to indirectly find its qualities, by observing the different conservations. But one thing I didn't understand is: We can't say  that the isospin in the left side is 1? Is it not like for example the baryon number, which you sum it? But thx for the insight

Comment: Isospin is like spin; so two isodoublets compose symmetrically to an isotriplet, or, anti symmetrically, to an isosinglet. But, ideally, you should check the generalized Pauli principle constraints.

Comment: Pauli principle contrains? This was never mentioned in our lectures. I will be sure to check it. Thx!

Comment: Oh, don't mind me. It means, overall, fermion pairs have to be in an antisymmetric state, and bosons in a symmetric one, under interchange.

Comment: I see, something along the lines that the wave function for bosons is symmetric when you change the position of two observed particles and anti symmetric for fermions. Cosma, one additional question regarding this exercise. If I want to find out from how many quarks and antiquarks this unknown particle H is made of, is there like a site or a program which by giving the information that I was able to  find about this particle can directly tell me about it's composition, meaning quark anti-quark build up?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126637/discussion-between-imbaf-and-cosmas-zachos).